# Displacement map filter not working on rotated object

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am trying to make mirrored pattern, but when I add displacement filter, it seems it only works on first and fourth quandrant. Am I overlooking some beginner mistake or is this behavior expected?

```html
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%"/>
        </clipPath>

        <pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4"  patternTransform="scale(20) rotate(0)">
          <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2
                 M0,4 l4,-4
                 M3,5 l2,-2"
              style="stroke:red; stroke-width:1" />
        </pattern>

        <symbol id="quarter">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
        </symbol>

        <filter id="noise" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="8" />
        </filter>
    </defs>


    <g filter="url(#noise)">
      <use xlink:href="#quarter"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(90)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(180)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(270)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing an xChannelSelector or yChannelSelector - one of which is required.

(Update - as you mention in the comment, when you leave this out, it defaults to using the alpha channel in both X and Y - so it will shift everything up and down the top/left bottom/right diagonal axis - so solid color diagonal lines with this orientation will only show distortions at their starting and finishing edges).

If you're not going to process the feTurbulence in some way after you generate it, then any one of the channels (RGBA) works as a displacement source - since Perlin noise is equally noisy in all four channels.

(You don't need to use the R channel because your shapes are red - that's backwards - the channel selector applies to your noise input, not your the shape you want to apply it to.)

```html
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%"/>
        </clipPath>

        <pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4"  patternTransform="scale(20) rotate(0)">
          <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2
                 M0,4 l4,-4
                 M3,5 l2,-2"
              style="stroke:red; stroke-width:1" />
        </pattern>

        <symbol id="quarter">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
        </symbol>

        <filter id="noise" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="8" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>


    <g filter="url(#noise)">
      <use xlink:href="#quarter"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(90)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(180)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(270)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I looked up the specs and ChannelSelector is optional defaulting to A. Little tinkering with trying to replace symbols with bitmap and rotating it, when it hit me. SVG coords are from top left, when you displace pixel by the same value (since both X and Y default to same A value) it will be moved on diagonal, so while pixels are actually displaced, diagonal still rest mainly untouched. Specifying different channel selectors solves this. Accepting as answer since you hinted me in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In your filter I've added `xChannelSelector="R"` for the `feDisplacementMap`. I'm using `R` for red since your shapes are red.

```
    <filter id="noise" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="3" />
            <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="8" xChannelSelector="R" />
    </filter>
```

```html
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%"/>
        </clipPath>

        <pattern id="diagonalHatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4"  patternTransform="scale(20) rotate(0)">
          <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2
                 M0,4 l4,-4
                 M3,5 l2,-2"
              style="stroke:red; stroke-width:1" />
        </pattern>

        <symbol id="quarter">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
        </symbol>

        <filter id="noise" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="3" result="noise" seed="3" />
                <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="8" xChannelSelector="R" />
        </filter>
    </defs>


    <g filter="url(#noise)">
      <use xlink:href="#quarter"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(90)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(180)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#quarter" style="transform-origin: 50% 50%;" transform="rotate(270)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Also I would have applied the filter to the `<rect>` inside `<symbol>` instead of applying it to the group.

Comment: Whoa, it works. The filter must be applied to whole, otherwise you get jagged transitions on edges, this way everything is continuous. The channel selector works with andy value other than default A (and works with all other fills, not just red). What I don't get, either there is no alpha, and then no displacement should take place, or there is alpha, and all the quadrants should be displacemented. Why this isn't the case?